# AngularJS passing element rto function

Tags: angularjs

I am lately working on an AngularJS Application and need to pass element to a function so i can access it in controller implementation. See the code:

```
<textarea class="responsive-textarea" id="textarea" ng-model="textCtrl.textarea"
          ng-change="textCtrl.resize($event);">
</textarea>
```

//Controller Class

```
public resize(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

Console is logging "undefined" value and throws and error when trying to log `event.currentTarget`

The desired resultis to make the textarea resize each time value is changed

Answer (score 0):

```
The desired result is to make the textarea resize each time value is changed
```

First of all - you can look for ready solutions on the web.

If you want to do it yourself - write directive, it is bad idea usually to manipulate elements directly in controller. You will have something like this as result:

```
<textarea my-resisze...

app.directive('myResize', () => {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: (scope, el, attrs, ngModelCtrl) => {
        ngModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(() => {
            console.log(el); // resize here
        });
    }
  }
})
```